# how to remove a CSS property using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I remove( not set null) a CSS property from a class? Here I have a class named myclass it contains the property right:0px. I am trying to remove `right:0px` from my class(not trying to set null). How can I make it possible?

```
.myclass{
    position:fixed;
    right:0px;
}
```

Comment: remove the class or change the class

Comment: maybe initial or inherit will be helpfull in your case

Comment: What do you mean by "remove" ? Remove `right:0px;` from `css` at `style` element or file ? What is expected result ?

Comment: the expect res is  .myclass{
position:fixed;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do following way using JQuery. It will set `initial` value of right.

```js
$('.myclass').css({ 'right' : 'initial' });
```

```css
.myclass{
position:fixed;
right:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclass">
test
</div>
```

Comment: initial means? can u explane

Comment: @kannanD.S initial means default value of right. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial and https://css-tricks.com/getting-acquainted-with-initial/

Answer (score 0):

You should not change the initial css, because it's already included. What you could do is add a new css class and reset the `right` property:

```
.myResetClass {
  right: auto !important;
}
```

Then append this class to necessary elements, which will change the `right` property to default `auto`:

```
$('.myclass').addClass('myResetClass');
```

Comment: any other technique?

Comment: @kannanD.S Nope, I guess this is the correct approach. You cannot modify a defined class in css. Just use another class and change what you need.

Comment: iam facing the language rotation issue (RTL). is this the right way?

Comment: @kannanD.S It is how css should be used.

Comment: @ Dmitri Pavlutin i got the result using "initial". thx for your valuable support

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've seen jQuery control a CSS declaration like what you want, but from what I've seen that's not the best way to handle it. Instead create these classes:

```
.myclass1 {position:fixed;}
.myclass2 {right:0px}
```

and use the two classes in your element like

```
<input class="myclass1 myclass2" ...
```

Then when you want to remove the `right:0px`, all you need to do is to remove the class that handles that:

```
$('input.myclass1').removeClass('myclass2');
```

To put it back, use `addClass`

```
$('input.myclass1').addClass('myclass2');
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I Know, JQuery cannot manipulate CSS rules specified for a particular class. What you can do though is set CSS rules for another class.

```
.myclass{
position:fixed;
right:0px;
}

.anotherclass{
position:fixed;
}
```

then using jquery

```
$(selector).removeClass('myclass').addClass('anotherclass');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this:

```
$(".myclass").css({ 'right' : 'inherit' });
```

If you want to remove inline.. [This will](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_removeattr) be useful

Answer (score 0):

> the expect res is .myclass{ position:fixed; }

Try using `$("style")` selector, `.each()`, `.text()`, `String.prototype.replace()`

```js
$(function() {
  $("style").each(function() {
    $(this).text(function(_, text) {
      return text.replace(/(\.myclass\s+\{\n\s+.+\n\s+.+\n\s+.+\})/g
      , function(match, p1) {
        var re = match.replace(/right:\s+\d+\w+;\n/g, "");
        return re
      })
    });
    console.log(this.textContent)
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<style>
  .myclass {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this:

```
$(".myclass").removeAttr("right");
```

Comment: What do you want remove or reset ?

Comment: .myclass {position:fixed;} iam expecting this out put